# MySQL multiple condition on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table "Transaction" with column

- ID(primary)
- Type (A or B)
- Status (0 or 1)

---

I want to execute "SELECT * from Transaction WHERE type = 'B' and status = 0", BUT this query can only return result if there is no Type "A" with status = 0. Is that possible to do that with one sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Transaction t
WHERE type = 'B' and status = 0 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Transaction t2
                  WHERE type = 'A' AND status = 0
                 );
```

Note:  Normally there would be a *correlation* clause which would connect to the subquery to the outer query.

Comment: Thanks Man :) I think it works just what as I expected